# SQL Query to pull date range based on dates in a table

Tags: sql, date, reporting-services

I have some SQL code which is contained in an SSRS report and when run pulls a list of student detentions for a set period such as a week or month but I have been asked to get the report to run automatically from the start of the current school term to the date the report has been run.  Is this possible?  We have 3 terms per year and the dates change  each year.  The report has multiple subscriptions which will run weekly and filter to students in particular day houses and years so we ideally need the report to update itself.

We have a table in our database titled TblSchoolManagementTermDates which includes txtStartDate and txtFinishDate columns for each term.

The date of the detention is stored in the column detPpl.dDetentionDate

The full SQL code I am currently using is:

```
SELECT ppl.txtSchoolID AS SchoolID,
   detPpl.TblDisciplineManagerDetentionsPupilsID AS DetentionID,
   ppl.txtSurname AS Surname,
   ppl.txtForename AS Forename,
   ppl.txtPrename AS PreferredName,
   ppl.intNCYear AS Year,
   ppl.txtAcademicHouse AS House,
   schTermDates.intSchoolYear AS AcademicYear,
   schTerms.txtName AS TermName,
   CAST(schTermDates.intSchoolYear AS CHAR(4)) + '/' +
         RIGHT(CAST(schTermDates.intSchoolYear + 1 AS CHAR(4)), 2) AS AcademicYearName,
   detPpl.dDetentionDate AS DetentionDate,
   detSessions.txtSessionName AS DetentionName,
   detPpl.txtOffenceDescription AS OffenceDescription,
   LEFT(Staff.Firstname, 1) + '. ' + Staff.Surname AS PutInBy,
   detPpl.intPresent AS AttendedDetention
FROM dbo.TblPupilManagementPupils AS ppl
 INNER JOIN
 dbo.TblDisciplineManagerDetentionsPupils AS detPpl
 ON detPpl.txtSchoolID = ppl.txtSchoolID
 INNER JOIN
 dbo.TblDisciplineManagerDetentionsSessions AS detSessions
 ON detPpl.intDetentionSessionID = detSessions.TblDisciplineManagerDetentionsSessionsID
 INNER JOIN
 dbo.TblStaff AS Staff
 ON Staff.User_Code = detPpl.txtSubmittedBy
 INNER JOIN
 dbo.TblSchoolManagementTermDates AS schTermDates
 ON detPpl.dDetentionDate BETWEEN schTermDates.txtStartDate AND schTermDates.txtFinishDate
 INNER JOIN
 dbo.TblSchoolManagementTermNames AS schTerms
 ON schTermDates.intTerm = schTerms.TblSchoolManagementTermNamesID
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
 dbo.TblDisciplineManagerDetentionsCancellations AS Cancelled
 ON Cancelled.intSessionID = detPpl.intDetentionSessionID
 AND Cancelled.dDetDate = detPpl.dDetentionDate
WHERE (ppl.txtAcademicHouse = 'Challoner') AND (Cancelled.TblDisciplineManagerDetentionsCancellationsID IS NULL) AND (CAST(detPpl.dDetentionDate AS DATE) >= CAST (GETDATE()-28 AS DATE))
```

ORDER BY ppl.txtSurname, ppl.txtForename, detPpl.dDetentionDate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to assign a couple of parameters to this code.

lets call the parameters

> @term_start

and

> @term_end

In your where clause you simply need to remove this piece

```
AND (CAST(detPpl.dDetentionDate AS DATE) >= CAST (GETDATE()-28 AS DATE))
```

and add this piece in

```
AND (CAST(detPpl.dDetentionDate AS DATE) between @term_start and @term_end
```

Now create another dataset based on your term dates - lets call the dataset term_dates

something like this (I'm making up these fields as I don't know what columns are available or have no sample data) Use the idea below to adapt to your requirements

```
select 

min(term_start_date) as start_date
,max(term_end_date) as end_date

from TblSchoolManagementTermNames

where convert(date,getdate()) between term_start_date and term_end_date
```

Now your report should have 2 parameters.. You simply need to set the default value for the parameters.

Set the default value for @term_start as the start_date and @term_end as the end_date from your term_dates dataset

Run your report.. You should have the data between the term dates.

This should work.. unless I've misunderstood the requirement

Comment: Thank you very much for this and replying so quickly.  I had to amend the new query to change the date format to yyyy/mm/dd as it was returning dd/mm/yyyy which meant no results were being returned but otherwise it works perfectly.