# SQL Query to pull date range with missing dates in a table

Tags: sql, date, reporting-services

This is a follow on from a previous question I asked which can be found here:

[SQL Query to pull date range based on dates in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60153785/sql-query-to-pull-date-range-based-on-dates-in-a-table)

The database I am pulling data from includes school term dates in the table dbo.TblSchoolManagementTermDates but does not include any date ranges for the holiday periods.  This means that if the report runs based according to the schedule (which is every Monday) and the date falls within a holiday period the report becomes disabled as it fails to run due to invalid parameters.  I then have to re-enable the report when we are back in term time.

We are unable to add additional rows to the table so need to somehow modify the query to pull through other dates.  In an ideal world the report would not run but would remain enabled and run the next time the date falls within a term time but the options for the SSRS schedule are not that advanced.

There are 2 possible options that I can think of.

Firstly it would be fine for it to just enter the date the subscription runs on into both the txtStartDate and the txtFinishDate fields if this is possible and the recipients can just delete the emails.

Secondly if the report was able to place the date within the school year instead which runs from 1st September to 31st August each year and then pull 1st September as the startdate and 31st August as the enddate.  The only problem with this is that it would need to correctly set the year.  For example if the report was run on 1st January 2022 it would need to pull 1st September 2021 as the start date and 31st August 2022 as the end date.

The current SQL query is as follows:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(varchar(17), MIN(txtStartDate), 111) AS start_date,
    CONVERT(varchar(17), MAX(txtFinishDate), 111) AS end_date
FROM  TblSchoolManagementTermDates
WHERE (CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) BETWEEN txtStartDate AND txtFinishDate)
```

Would anyone be able to help in suggesting an amendment to the query to get this to work for me?

Many thanks in advance.

Stuart

[Term Dates Table Image]
[image]

[Current Query with output based on today's date]
[image]

The School year is made up of 3 terms starting from September to August.  For the sake of the report we can say from 1st September to 31st August.

I suggested 2 possible solutions but feel free to recommend others.  The first option could look at the take and if it cannot find any dates that match it could simply return the date the report is run on for both the start and end dates.

The second solution would mean that any date from 01/09/2021 to 31/08/2021 would bring through a start date of 01/09/21 and an end date of 31/08/2022.  Any date from 01/01/2022 to 31/08/2022 would bring through a start date of 01/09/21 and an end date of 31/08/2022. This would need to dynamically update each year.

Comment: Can you show a sample of your table and the results expected based on a couple of dates.

Comment: Thanks Alan.  I have updated the original post with screenshots and further info.